# How to access array first element within an array in jsx react?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I am trying to access the first image but Facing errors. I can access it with map function but I don't want all Images just the first one.
But it is not allowing me to access that without map function

Task is to get first image of every city

Error is :
Cannot read property 'image' of undefined.

```
cities:[
        {
          City:"city1",
          Images:[
                  {title: "first image" , image: "url"},
                  {title: "second image" , image: "url"}
                 ]
        },
        {
          City:"city2",
          Images:[
                  {title: "first image" , image: "url"},
                  {title: "second image" , image: "url"}
                 ]
        },
]
```

```
 {cities.map((city, index) => {
   return (
        <div key={index}>
          <img src={url + city.Images[0].image} alt={url + city.Images[0].image} /> // Getting Error here
          <p style={{ color: "#ea4c89", fontSize: '25px', fontWeight: "600", marginTop: "50px" }}>{city.City}</p>
        </div>
         )
 })}
```

Comment: The images array is empty.

Comment: Based on just the code you've provided I think this should just work. Did you console.log the value of city? What is in there? Alsof you're trying to access `city.Images[0].image` which should be `city.Images[0].image_url`, but thats not the problem.

Comment: logic looks good, check input data. second sub objects don't have image key

Comment: I console.log the result ...In console it is showing the result.

https://ibb.co/7KmX53x

Comment: image_url was just a mistake while typing question I corrected it the question

Comment: Can you create a demo of the problem in codesandbox and share the link?

Comment: tried your code in codesandbox, and it has no errors. What the error have you got?

Answer (score 0):

I cant't comment so I must write this i answer

Maybe there is a short time while rendering when data is not loaded and you trying to access it? Map function will not throw an error while maping empty array but accesing index will. Try add if statement and return only if loaded

Comment: If check is already present there.

cities.map will only perform if the there is data in cities array